# Why show usage numbers on the website?

Tags: user-behavior, marketing, numbers, statistics

Many websites show their usage statistics. For example, [this website](http://bufferapp.com/) on the bottom of the page shows the number of people that are using the website at the moment, and how many updates were made. It's also constantly updated. Other websites show the number of registered users and other stats.

It seems cool, and, presumably, creates trust and interest in the product. But these are just my ideas. I would like to hear your thoughts and a reference to related research if exists.

Comment: I think it's basic marketing. "Lots of people love our product! You should too!"

Comment: [Herd Mentality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herd_mentality).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is quite simple. This kind of data ("number of users", "number of posts", "number of sales" etc.) are used as social proof to drive sales/sign ups to your product. It is much easier to trust something that is used by millions of people, right?

For example Tumblr emphasizes the most crucial data for their micro-blogging platform, the number of blogs and posts, right on their sign up page.

[image: Tumblr login page]

I think these numbers might be a good ice breaker for user to actually try the product. It can also be accompanied by user testimonials which add more personal recommendation. Basecamp homepage as example:

[image: Basecamp homepage]

Answer (score 2):

Website statistics and analytics is the only driver for commercial sales price. There is almost nothing else as simple as "Visitors" to work with. Because of that, websites that don't sell products need to show number of visitors, no of clicks, no of unique users by hour, day and month.

The more visitors, clicks, unique users you got, the higher the sales price. And this is true even if everyone already knows that hit rate is useless and what you really should care about is [conversion rat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_marketing#Conversion_rate)e.

Sadly, the change from hit rate to conversion rate is taking too long, IMHO.

[image]

More to read: [Web Analytics 2.0 by Avinash Kaushik](http://www.webanalytics20.com)

Comment: I don't disagree, but the example in the question wasn't actually referring to site visitors, but rather the number of users of a product.

Comment: I disagree DA01, Benny is answering the question spot on. I quote: "Because of that, websites that don't sell products need to show number of visitors, no of clicks, **no of unique users** by hour, day and month."

Comment: @Bluewater I'm making a distinction between "web site visitor/user" and "people who use our product that we sell". I admit, on second reading, that that's perhaps a fuzzy distinction and maybe not all that important. That said, I do think there is a difference between the more traditional 'hit counter' type of stat vs. 'number of confirmed customers using our product'--but maybe that difference is irrelevant to this particular question.